# Marshalling a large list of objects giving OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, performance, memory-management, jaxb

I am trying to marshal a large list of objects ~1 million and it's giving OutOfMemoryError while trying to the add the objects in the Arraylist at ~20K objects. I would like to have a single XML file. How can I achieve this?

Note : I do have a JVM memory limitation of 512MB

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the items in the xml file as you load them. It is clear that you cannot add in a collection as ArrayList a lot of items but keeping the memory low.

In this case you need to write the XML in file using something like: XMLStreamWriter.
Avoid using libraries which loads everything in memory before writing to disk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that in a 64bit machine each pointer costs 8 bytes. This is the reason why when you try to load a large collection you are not just loading the data , you are allocating memory for each field, each attribute of the object model and each membver of your collection.

You have three options:

- to allocate more memory.
- To find a more compact format when you put everything in memory.
- third is to implement some sort of scrolling so that you load only part of the set at a time.

Comment: can you please provide reference for 3rd option : ...load only part of the set at a time.